# Sticky header on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I need a sticky header on a mobile browser. I'm currently using this jquery script:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var stickyHeader = $('#persist-wrap').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeader ) {
        $('#persist-wrap').addClass("sticky");
      } else {
        $('#persist-wrap').removeClass("sticky");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

with this CSS code:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

The header has an id of persist-wrap. This works fine on a desktop browser but not at all on a mobile browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: In which mobile platforms do you see the issue?

Comment: Tested it on iphone 4/4S and Android phones using their respective browsers.

Comment: this article has some interesting insights in the topic: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: I think that man has delay before sticky header appears while user scrolls. Actually you can test it, it will appear only after user moved his finger off and scrolling momentum is finished. I can't fix this problem anyhow. I checked all famous websites and see that they removed fixed second header row and added "scroll to top" arrow at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I've tweaked your example a little and it works for me on the Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS and iPad 3 running iOS 6.01: (don't have any others to hand to test it on).

**List of changes**

- I cached all the objects that were used multiple times.
- Changed it so its a reusable function accepting a parameter of an object so it can be applied multiple times (this could be tweaked to accept multiple objects at once).

Here's the example:

```js
$(function(){
  
 createSticky(jQuery("#header"));

});

function createSticky(sticky) {
 
 if (typeof sticky !== "undefined") {

  var pos = sticky.offset().top,
    win = jQuery(window);
   
  win.on("scroll", function() {
      win.scrollTop() >= pos ? sticky.addClass("fixed") : sticky.removeClass("fixed");      
  });   
 }
}
```

```css
#header {
 background: #666;
 padding: 3px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
#header.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}


/* For aesthetics only */
    
body {
 margin: 0;
    height: 10000px;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some Text before the header</p>
<div id="header">
  Home
</div>
```